# TextView can't draw on Canvas correctly after calling setText() and invalidate()

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, textview, android-view

My purpose is to make an `Bitmap` image which shows user supplied text, and the image can later be saved into cache.

After calling  `TextView.setText()` and `TextView.invalidate()`, the `TextView` is not being updated as I expected. It still draws previous texts on `Canvas`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // tv is a TextView and et is an EditText.
    tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
    tv.invalidate();
    // if measure() isn't called, getMeasuredWidth() returns previous value.tv.measure(0, 0);

    int screenWidth = (int) tv.getMeasuredWidth();
    int screenHeight = (int) tv.getMeasuredHeight();

    if (screenHeight * screenWidth != 0) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                                    screenWidth, screenHeight);
        Bitmap testB;

        testB = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(testB);

        tv.draw(c);
        // tv draws previous String on Canvas c.

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        iv.setImageBitmap(testB);
    }
}
```

The document says

> `public void invalidate ()`
>
> Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible,
>   `onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)` will be called at some point in the
>   future. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI
>   thread, call `postInvalidate()`.

Does it mean I should override the `onDraw()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution... (may be a solution)

It is needed to add this line before calling draw():

```
tv.layout(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

I think the width and height aren't updated yet, because getWidth() returns previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate means its a just refresh kind of thing. Once you try with gone and bring to front it should work. E.g :

```
// Try this ...
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
tv.bringToFront();
tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be updated, you don't even need to call `invalidate()`. Maybe there is a problem in some other place in your code. Your `onClick` function seems right to me.